# Subject and object while using passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, subjects, objects

My English teacher and an overwhelming majority of my English class insists that in the following sentences the bolded words are **subjects** and the italicized words are *objects*.

> **I** ate the *cake*.
>
> The *cake* was eaten by **me**.

The first sentence is obviously correct, but I'm fairly certain that in the second sentence "cake" is the subject and "eaten by me" is the object.

> The **cake** was *eaten by me*.

May I have some concrete evidence proving or disproving my point?

Comment: Have you tried looking in a grammar book?

Comment: Both you and your English teacher are wrong. In the second sentence, the subject is "The cake" and there is no object. The verb is "was eaten" and "by me" is a prepositional phrase modifying the verb.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Canonical_passives

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first sentence, traditional grammar regards *I* as the subject and *the cake* as the object. In the second sentence, *the cake* is the subject and there is no object.

Functional grammar, however, takes a rather different view. It calls the subject and object Participants and the verb a Process. In the first sentence, *I* and *the cake* are Participants and *ate* is a Process. More specifically, *I* is the Actor, *the cake* is the Goal and *ate* is a Material Process. In the second sentence, *me* remains the Actor and *the cake* remains the Goal, even though their structural roles have changed.

Comment: Isn't the idea that this semantic analysis runs *alongside* the syntactic analysis of subject/object? A functional analysis doesn't change the syntactic identification of subject/object as such, it just adds an extra layer of analysis. Or is there a specific model of functional grammar where this isn't the case?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the Subject is essentially regarded as being the element with which the verb agrees. In your passive example, "the cake" is the subject: change this to "the cakes" and you see that the verb changes from "was" to "were", whereas changing "me" to "us" or "them" makes no difference to the verb form.

There are a few exceptions and corner cases, notably a phenomenon whereby what you might regard as a 'structural' subject position actually gets filled with a "dummy" or "filler" subject (think about a sentences such as "There appeared before him a ghostly figure" or "Let there be light"). But by and large for your purposes here, you can regard the subject as the element that agrees with the verb.